# User interface in iOS. Sizes of elements for iphone with retina?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, iphone-4, retina-display

[I need something like this](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html)

But I have found nothing similar to this one for iphone with retina display

Comment: For the retina display can follow this , reminding you that the images (only those), must be contained in double dimension @ 2x

Comment: I need to prepare images for retina display so I need a real size in pixels.I must convert all the sizes in this picture to pixels for retina manually and it is not a reason to vote down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're designing your own interface elements and need image dimensions, yes; you just double the values. However, in your code, when referring to the coordinate system of elements (points), you still use then 320x480 point system, as the points are automatically scaled for different device resolutions.

For images, the retina sized images must have the same file name, but with @2x following. For instance, background.png (320x480) must have a similar image background@2x.png with dimensions 640x960.

Comment: simply i didn't know the height of a status bar and a navigation bar to create an image with a correct size

Answer (score 2):

Notice how the measurements are in points (not pixels). This is the correct sizing for both retina and normal iPhone displays.

1 point == 1 pixel on non-retina displays and 1 point == 2 pixels on retina displays.